# jquery is not defined

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь подключить плагин, чтобы на сайте была возможность включить версию для слабовидящих.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <html lang="ru">
    
        <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Сайт учителя-логопеда Будаевой Людмилы Владимировны</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/css/bvi.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     
        
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
        


        
        
        <style> 
            
            header {
                display: block;
                            }
            .header-bg {
    background: url(images/fon13.png) no-repeat center bottom; 
                /* Животные */
    height: 300px; /* Высота шапки */
    text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
   }
   .header-bg img {
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
    top: 40px; /* Сдвигаем картинку вниз */
   }
            
 body {
background: url(images/fon4.jpg);
 background-position: center center; /*Задает начальное положение фонового изображения, установленного с помощью свойства background-image.*/
   background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Определяет, как будет повторяться фоновое изображение, установленное с помощью свойства background-image. Можно установить повторение рисунка только по горизонтали, по вертикали или в обе стороны. */
    background-attachment: fixed; /*Свойство background-attachment устанавливает, будет ли прокручиваться фоновое изображение вместе с содержимым элемента. Изображение может быть зафиксировано и оставаться неподвижным, либо перемещаться совместно с документом*/
 background-size: cover; /*Масштабирует фоновое изображение согласно заданным размерам.*/
 

}

            
            
            
            <div class="bvi-hide">Текст скроется когда включите версию сайта для слабовидящих</div>

</style> 

    
    
    </head>
    
    
        
        
        
        
        
        <body>
            
          
<a href="#" class="bvi-panel-open">Версия для слабовидящих</a> 
            

            
        
         <div class="header-bg">
    
   </div>
        
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: bisque">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">ОБЩИЕ СВЕДЕНИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="normi.html">НОРМЫ РЕЧЕВОГО РАЗВИТИЯ</a></li>
          <li><a href="rech.html">НАРУШЕНИЯ РЕЧИ</a></li>
          <li><a href="spec.html">КОГДА ОБРАТИТЬСЯ К СПЕЦИАЛИСТУ</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННАЯ И ДЫХАТЕЛЬНАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="agym.html">АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="dgym.html">ДЫХАТЕЛЬНАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА</a></li>
              
            
            
          </ul>
        </li>
          
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">МОИ РАБОТЫ <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="rrabota.html">РАБОТА С РОДИТЕЛЯМИ</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="prabota.html">РАБОТА С ПЕДАГОГАМИ</a></li>
              
            
            
          </ul>
        </li>
          
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="НАЙТИ ЧТО НИБУДЬ">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ПОИСК</button>
      </form>
     
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    
         <p class="test"><img src="images/mama1.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" vspace="5"></p> 
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p id="test2"><big><big>Уважаемые педагоги и родители! 
Всех посетителей сайта  приветсвует 
учитель-логопед Будаева Людмила Владимировна! </big></big></p></div>
        
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <ul class="test1">
        <li><b>Уровень образования</b> - высшее.МГГУ им. М А Шолохова, специальность "Логопедия" </li>
            <li><b>Квалификация</b>: учитель-логопед.</li>
            <li><b>Общий стаж работы</b>: 30 лет.</li>
            <li><b>Стаж работы по специальности</b>: 30 лет</li>
            <li><b>Данные о повышении квалификации и профессиональной переподготовке</b>: 
                <b>2013г</b> - обучение по модульным программам повышение квалификации для специалистов образовательных учреждений и психолого-педагогических комиссий- логопедов, психологов, социальных педагогов, дефектологов, обеспечивающих распространение организованно правовых моделей успешной социализации детей с ОВЗ и детей-инвалидов, на базе стажировочных площадок, Минобразования и науки РФ, Научно-образовательный центр "Социальная защита детей и молодежи" МГГУ им. М.А.Шолохова, 40ч.
                <b>2015 год</b> - БОУ ДПО (ПК)С " Чувашский республиканский институт образования" Минобразования и молодежной политики ЧР по теме: " Профессиональная компетентность учителя-логопеда в рамках требований ФГОС", удостоверение, 72ч.</li>
            <li><b>Награды</b>: Почетная грамота управления образования администрации г.Чебоксары, 2013.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
    
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip1-23.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        
       

        
       
         
</div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
     
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip4-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip2-4.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip3-7.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
            
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip5-6.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip6-5.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip7-2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip8-3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/2-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
</div>
        
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/3-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/4-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/5-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
           
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/6-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
           
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/7-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
            
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/8-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
          
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/9-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
            
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/10-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
            
        </div>
        
        
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/11-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
             
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/12-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
             
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/13-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
             
        </div>
        
            <div class="scrollup">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>
                <a href="#" id="up">наверх</a>
            </div>
        
        
        
<!-- UItoTop plugin -->
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Starting the plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
/*
var defaults = {
containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
scrollSpeed: 1200,
easingType: 'linear'
};
*/
 
$().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
 
});
</script>
    
            
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
                 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            
            
            <script src='button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/responsivevoice.min.js?ver=1.5.0'></script> 
<script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi-init-panel.js"></script> 
<script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi.min.js"></script> 
<script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/js.cookie.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bvi-panel-open').bvi('Init', {
    "BviPanel": "1",
    "BviPanelBg": "white",
    "BviPanelFontSize": "12",
    "BviPanelLetterSpacing": "normal",
    "BviPanelLineHeight": "normal",
    "BviPanelImg": "1",
    "BviPanelImgXY": "1",
    "BviPanelReload": "0",
    "BviCloseClassAndId": ".hide-screen-fixed",
    "BviFixPanel": "1",
    "BviPlay": "1"
  });
});
```

Comment: сам jquery надо подключать раньше, чем плагины использующие его

Comment: @teran читал эту фразу здесь же, но смысл понять не могу, конкретнее можно? что это значит?

Comment: Перенесите подключение jquery куда-нибудь в `<head>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jquery` должен подключится раньше вешнего `main.js`

```
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script src='button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/responsivevoice.min.js?ver=1.5.0'></script> 
    <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi-init-panel.js"></script> 
    <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: да, вопрос решился, спасибо!
единственное осталась одна ошибка критическая 'document is not defined. [no - undef]' 
это тоже критично?